# regarding the parameter for imp.load_source

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I once saw the following `python` code. Here f represents a full path pointing to a `python` file, I am not clear what does `"arch_%s" % postfix`  used for? and how does `postfix` work here?

```
arch = imp.load_source("arch_%s" % postfix, f)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument is just a name to reference the loaded code as a regular module, and has nothing to do with the second part of the question. The `%` notation is the old `format` notation. It's similar to `printf` formatting, so

```
"arch_%s"%post_fix
```

will just insert `post_fix` as a string (`%s` - you can use others such as `%d` in my next example), so if `post_fix=64` you would get

```
arch_64
```

It's better to use format usually, if it's not a trivial substitution and as a rule:

```
"arch_{}".format(post_fix)
```

Comment: So, with respect to the above example, load_source just load the python file named as f, and the loaded module was given a name as arch_64, is my understanding correct? Thanks.

Comment: @user297850 I need to be clear - 'arch_64' is the name of the module, but you would still access the module through what you defined as `arch`. The name is for Python. This will allow importing the file several times under different aliases (never used that but possible).

Answer (score 0):

it is called [String formatting](http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/formatting_strings.html) in Python. It use to append a certain string variable to anoter raw string. Therefore, in your example it will append the string stored in `post_fix` to the string `'arch_'`.

**Python 3**

Since you added python-3x as a tag it is relevant to tell you that in python 3 you should use [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/string.html#string-formatting) instead. Here is a lot of good [examples](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-examples). It is actually better suited for this type of operations since it handles more wanted behavior. This is from the documentation;

> This section contains examples of the new format syntax and comparison
>   with the old %-formatting.
>
> In most of the cases the syntax is similar to the old %-formatting,
>   with the addition of the {} and with : used instead of %. For example,
>   '%03.2f' can be translated to '{:03.2f}'.
>
> The new format syntax also supports new and different options, shown
>   in the follow examples.

**Basic use cases**

*In python 2.x*

```
sentence = raw_input("Enter your name?")
print "Hi %s" %name
```

*In python 3.x*

```
name = input("Enter your name?")
print ("Hi {}".format(name))
```